# PopViewControllerAnimated:YES when tap on UIAlertView make Keyboard appear in parentVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I tried to programmatically popViewcontroller
By doing this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

   [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

The problem is I have textFields in this VC.If the textField is active and keyboard is displaying, and if I display the AlertView with use to command to resign keyboard ( `[[self view] endEditing:YES] or [textField resignFirstResponder]` ).  And then call the command popViewControllerAnimated:YES  .  The current VC is dismissed but briefly after the parent VC is appear. There will be a keyboard shown for like 1 second and then disappear.

This behaviour is very annoying. Are there anyway to solve this ? I noticed that by  using `[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO]`  The keyboard won't appear . But I prefer to have animation in my app.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem my making the    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; delayed when called.

```
   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 100 *      NSEC_PER_MSEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@KongHantrakool 's answer works but also has a shortage, you can add [[self view] endEditing:YES] or [textField resignFirstResponder]  in - (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView ,it will be better.

Comment: I had to use this solution as well as the marked answer to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code:

```
#pragma mark - UIAlertView Delegate

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(popViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)popViewController {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think its may help you

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too, and I found out that the delay solution does not work at all. `alertView` will remember the status of the keyboard, so when the alertView is dismissed, it will restore the keyboard. So the issue comes out: the keyboard appears about 1 second after we pop the viewController.

Here is my solution:
We just need to ensure the keyboard's status is hidden, before we pop the viewcontroller.

1. First we add a property and register the keyboard notifications to monitor the keyboard's status:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
@property (nonatomic) BOOL keyboardDidShow;
```

2. Implement the funs:keyboardDidHide: and keyboardDidShow:

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.keyboardDidShow = NO;
    if (self.needDoBack) {
        self.needDoBack = NO;
        [self showBackAlertView];

    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.keyboardDidShow = YES;
}
```

3. Do your pop:

```
- (void)back {
    if (self.keyboardDidShow) {
        self.needDoBack = YES;
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    } else {
        [self showBackAlertView];
    }
}
```